# Why doesn't CQ run OSLC requests paralley?

Tags: session, clearquest, oslc

I run some jenkins job parallely . Each job sends an OSLC API request to ClearQuest webserver in same time.
I recognize these requests are resolved sequentially instead of paralelly.
Each request takes 5 seconds approx.
Response times are:

1. 1st request take ~5 seconds
2. 2nd request take ~10 seconds (you see it's waiting 1st to finish)
3. 3th request take ~15 seconds (you see it's waiting 2st to finish)
4. 4th request take ~20 seconds (you see it's waiting 3st to finish)
5. and so on...

So it seems requests are took in a kind of queue. As though it was only one thread to resolve every  OSLC rest APIs. Is it possible?
With other words: is it possible to increase the number of CQ threads for concurrent OSLC rest api calls?

**Update:**
After a little investigation I see in cq's webserver's access log that requests have arrived to server in same time. So it's sure that CQ is not able to handle requests parallely.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer:
I realized that the basic authentication takes a long time like that in CQ indeed.
If I use the last session id in the api request then server response in a half second or less. Browser send session id automatically so I need to put [credentials: "include"] into request header.